# Script-fu unable to scale image after duplicating it

Tags: gimp, script-fu

The following is part of a larger Script-fu script that I am trying write.

I have run into a problem trying to duplicate .xcf file that is open and then scale it to some user specified dimension.

The following is what I though would work:

```
(define (my-duplicate-and-scale inImage inDrawable inWidth inHeight)
    (let* ((theDuplicateImage (gimp-image-duplicate inImage)))

        (gimp-image-scale theDuplicateImage inWidth inHeight)
    )
)

(script-fu-register
    "my-duplicate-and-scale"   ;func name
    "Duplicate and Scale ..."  ;menu label
    ""                         ;description
    ""                         ;author
    ""                         ;copyright notice
    ""                         ;date created
    "*"                        ;image type that the script works on
    SF-IMAGE    "Image"    0
    SF-DRAWABLE "Drawable" 0
    SF-VALUE    "Width"    "512"
    SF-VALUE    "Height"   "512"
)

(script-fu-menu-register "my-duplicate-and-scale" "<Image>/File/My")
```

When I execute the function I receive the following error:

```
Error while executing my-duplicate-and-scale:

Error: ( : 2) Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-scale
```

According to the Procedure Browser `gimp-image-duplicate` returns an `IMAGE` and the first parameter to `gimp-image-scale` is an `IMAGE`.

Comment: If you are not already used with scheme, maybe a better deal would be to learn Python for your scripts: it is a much more flexible language, wthout a lot of the catchs scheme has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

Replace:

```
(let* ((theDuplicateImage (gimp-image-duplicate inImage)))
```

with:

```
(let* ((theDuplicateImage (car (gimp-image-duplicate inImage))))
```

Comment: Your answer helped me figured out what I did wrong. What is actually returned is a list.  The list has one item, an IMAGE. i.e. a `( IMAGE )` not `IMAGE` .  Thanks